# Ambiguous use of subscript with Parse PFUser?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, subscript

Latest Xcode upgrade 7.3 broke the following block of code in a tableview:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GameCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GameViewCell

        if PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId == self.user1.objectId{
            let user = gameResults[indexPath.row]["user2"] as! PFUser
            cell.userName.text = user["first_name"] as! String
            self.viewUser = user
        }
```

The line `let user = gameResults[indexPath.row]["user2"] as! PFUser` returns error ambiguous subscript. I looked at other answers here about this issue so I tried to change it to `let user = )(gameResults[indexPath.row]["user2"] as NSArray) as! PFUser` but that didn't work.

How can I get this to work? Thanks!!

UPDATE:

I added an exclamation mark after the subscript and it seemed to get rid of the error. Like this:

`let user = gameResults[indexPath.row]["user2"]! as! PFUser`

Is this an acceptable way of fixing this?

Comment: What is `gameResults`?  How is it declared?

Comment: thanks for the reply! It's `var gameResults: [AnyObject] = []`

Comment: Your code would probably be clearer if you split the line into two; get the game result then get the user from it, checking the optional as appropriate

Comment: I fixed it by adding an exclamation mark but I'm not sure if that's ideal

Comment: Since your array is `[AnyObject]` Swift doesn't know whether a given object will implement ["user2"]. You should declare your array as `[PFOobject]` or whatever is actually in the array.  Or you can split it into two lines with a downcast as I suggested above